# Passing Parameters to useFactory()

Tags: angular

Practicing DI and Factory method, I want to pass some parameters to the Factory. So I wrote something like this:

```
const loggingImplementation: AnalyticsImplementation = {
  recordEvent: (metric: Metric): void => {
    console.log('The metric is:', metric);
    console.log('Sending to', destUrl);
  }
};

export function loggerFactory(http: HttpClient, destUrl: string): AnalyticsService {
  return new AnalyticsService(loggingImplementation);
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: 'API_URL', useValue: 'http://nsa.gov'},
    { provide: AnalyticsService, deps: [HttpClient, 'API_URL'], useFactory(http: HttpClient, destUrl: string): loggerFactory}
  ],
  declarations: [ ]
})

export class AnalyticsDemoModule1 {
}
```

But Angular gives me an error saying a semicolon is missing after `loggerFactory` so I think I am not using the correct syntax. Can you help tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the `(http: HttpClient, destUrl: string)`:

```
useFactory: loggerFactory
```

If you want to inject a `API_URL` you can use a special notation:

```
{
  provide: AnalyticsService,
  deps: [ HttpClient, new Inject('API_URL') ],
  useFactory: loggerFactory
}
```

And it should work. Whatever you define in `deps` will be passed on to the factory parameters

Comment: Thanks I had tried that too but then it gives me error on this line of code : console.log('Sending to', destUrl); that I had defined in that const above all of them

Comment: @Travolta I've updated my answer. You can also not just use `destUrl` like that